# How to use Getit e injection Container

Tags: flutter, dart, dependency-injection

I'm a beginner in Flutter but I want to understand how to use get_it and the Dependency Injection in general.But In particular, use RegisterLazySingleton for a dependency and I want to use it in a different class. How could I do that?
For example, in a specific class, i created everything i want to register, with GetIt.instance and registerLazySingleton ecc ecc
But after that, how i can use one dependency that i have registered?

Example:

\\Class for Get it\\

```
import 'package:get_it\get_it.dart';
import 'package:package_info_plus\package_info_plus.dart';
final di = GetIt.instance;

 FutureOr<void> _registerPackage()async{
     final packageInfo = await PackageInfo.fromPlatform();
    di.registerLazySingleton<PackageInfo>( () => packageInfo);
 }
```

}

\\OTHER CLASS\\
right here, how I can use packageInfo that I had register before?

Answer (score 0):

The class in which you want to use the injected object i.e `packageInfo` , you can simply do it by calling this

```
di.get<PackageInfo>();
```

Comment: i am not sure that it works correctly, because this registration is inside a function that was called before the runApp() methods...

Comment: Get_it registration should be done before runApp() method.

Comment: No sir, it doesn't work..

Comment: Because when I use di.get<PackageInfo>(); it seems like that PackageInfo isn't recognize..

Comment: use di.registerSingletonAsync instead of di.registerSingleton.